# Select2 - different color of selected tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a script analysing the tags IDs selected in Bootstrap Select2 and I'm trying to change a color of a tag in case of a condtion. Here is what I have:

```
$('#email_from').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.added) {
        last = e.val.length-1;
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email.informer.php',
            data: 'email_id=' + e.val[last],
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    $('.select2-search-choice:not(.selected_clr)', this).addClass('selected_clr');
                }
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    }
});
```

And I have css file with:

```
li.selected_clr {
    background-color: #633421 !important;
}
```

I read a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339828/how-to-change-the-css-of-color-of-select2-tags) but it doesn't work. No class gets added. If I replace it with:

```
$('.select2-search-choice').addClass('selected_clr');
```

then it works, but it changes color of all the tags while I need to do it only with the last one entered.

Comment: There is a quote missing in your code after #email_from in line 1.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have fixed that. I have that quote in the original code though.

Comment: Answered on this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339828/how-to-change-the-css-of-color-of-select2-tags/30878544#30878544