# Set a different color for each tag

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select2 where the users can select tags from a list or add new tags. WHen the user insert a new tag, I record it on a database. The user can, from other screen edit this tag and  associate it to a color. So my "tag" objects are like this:

```
{id:1, text:"cool tag", color:"#336699"}
```

What I would like to do is to show the tags with its colors inside the select2. I tried to do

```
formatSelection: function (tag) {
    return '<div style="background-color:'+tag.color+'">' + tag.text + '</div>';
},
```

but this does not change the background color of the div that holds the tag itself.

I also know I can use `formatSelectionCssClass` to add a css class to each item but in this case since the colors are user created, I do not have css classes with them (although if its the only way possible, is what I will do, dinamically generate a css file).

(PS.: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339828/how-to-change-the-css-of-color-of-select2-tags) looks like a solution but I was looking for something more elegant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do this:

```
data = function(){
  return [{id:1, text:"tag 1", color:"#555555"}, {id:2, text:"tag 2", color:"#336699"}]
},

formatSelectionCssClass = function(tag, container) {
    $(container).parent().css({ "background-color": tag.color });
};
```

Comment: Can you give more information on this? I can't figure out what you do

Comment: @Reign.85 He is defining a function which will be used as a rendering template. Ex.:

$('#dropdown').select2({
        templateSelection: formatSelectionCssClass
      });

This then sets the tag color to the color defined in the tag 'color' property.